# How to put a timestamp on a photo with Android

Tags: android

After taking a photograph with an Android phone, I would like to put a timestamp in the lower right corner. How can one do this without exhausting address space/memory? Typically, when I open large images, I get out of memory errors.

Do some phones support a Camera.Parameters option to do this?